# How to move text from old column to newly created columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code which is applied just for one column named 'Desc'. How can i change the code to apply it for two columns? 'Desc' and 'Desc1'?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Desc':['cat is black','dog is white']})
kw = ['cat','dog']
for k in kw:
   df[k + ' col'] = df.Desc.map(lambda s: s if k in s else '' )
```

[The output with just one column 'Desc' is:]

[image: 1]

But now i want to use this function to do the selection of two colums Desc and Desc1

Comment: Hello, I already loaded the image to see the desirable output

Comment: maybe you should use `apply(function)` to get full row in `function` and check both columns in every row.

Comment: you should show data with both columns and expected result for both columns. What if one column has `cat is whilte` and other has `cat is black` in the same row ?

Comment: I have no idea what you want in new column but you can alway do `df.Desc.map(...) + df.Desc1.map(...)` and it will concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Desc':['cat is black','dog is white']})
kw = ['cat','dog']

i = 0 #iterator
for k in kw:
    #Creates an empty column
    df[k + 'col'] = "" 
    #Assigns the value in the cell based on its location in df["Desc"]
    df[k + 'col'][i] = df["Desc"][i]
    i = i+1 #iterates
```

Comment: you don't have column `Desc1` in your code - so it doesn't resolve problem.

Comment: That's because OP modified their post. There was no Desc1 when they first asked the question....

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what result you expect but you can always use

```
df[k + ' col'] = df.Desc.map(...) + "," + df.Desc1.map(...)
```

But this will add `,` in empty cell and it will repeate duplicated values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Desc':  ['cat is black', 'dog is white'],
    'Desc1': ['cat is white', 'dog is white'],
})

kw = ['cat','dog']
for k in kw:
   df[k + ' col'] = df.Desc.map(lambda s: s if k in s else '') + ',' + df.Desc1.map(lambda s: s if k in s else '')
   
print(df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
           Desc         Desc1                    cat col                    dog col
0  cat is black  cat is white  cat is black,cat is white                          ,
1  dog is white  dog is white                          ,  dog is white,dog is white
```

---

But you can also use `.apply(function, args=[...], axis=1)` to send full row to function and run more complex code in function

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Desc':  ['cat is black', 'dog is white'],
    'Desc1': ['cat is white', 'dog is white'],
})

def select(row, word):
    result = []

    if word in row['Desc']:
        result.append(row['Desc'])

    if word in row['Desc1']:
        result.append(row['Desc1'])
        
    # skip duplicated
    if len(result) > 1 and result[0] == result[1]:
        result = result[:1]
        
    return ",".join(result)
    
kw = ['cat','dog']
for word in kw:
   df[f'{word} col'] = df.apply(select, args=[word], axis=1)
   
print(df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
           Desc         Desc1                    cat col       dog col
0  cat is black  cat is white  cat is black,cat is white              
1  dog is white  dog is white                             dog is white
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. Your answer is really useful, is the output I need. but now i am facing another problem. I published above my problem. Can you check it please?

Answer (score -1):

```
    def select(row, word):
    result = []
    if word in row ['Color']:
        result.append(row['Color'])
        
    if word in row ['Clorof']:
        result.append(row['Clorof'])    
   
    if word in row ['Diat']:
        result.append(row['Diat'])  
        
    if word in row ['Scene']:
        result.append(row['Scene'])
        
    if word in row ['Ciano']:
        result.append(row['Ciano'])
        
    if word in row ['Ameb_Cist']:
        result.append(row['Ameb_Cist'])
        
    if word in row ['Vortic']:
        result.append(row['Vortic'])
                          
    if word in row ['CiliadG']:
        result.append(row['CiliadG']) 
        
    if word in row ['Bact_fung']:
        result.append(row['Bact_fung'])  
        
    if word in row ['Bact_fil']:
        result.append(row['Bact_fil'])  
        
    if word in row ['Agl_EPS']:
        result.append(row['Agl_EPS']) 
        
    if word in row ['Microfla_ciliad']:
        result.append(row['Microfla_ciliad']) 
        
    if word in row ['Cristais']:
        result.append(row['Cristais']) 
        
    if len(result) > 1 and result[0] == result[1]:
        result = result[:1]
        
    return ",".join(result)

kw= ['descolor', 'clorofitas','Diatom', 'Scene', 'Cianobact', 'Cistos', 'Vorticelas', 'Ciliados', 'fungos', 'filam', 'Aglom','Microflag', 'Cristais']
for word in kw:
    df[f'{word} col'] = df.apply(select, args=[word], axis=1)
 
print(df.to_string())
```

Your answer is really useful, is the output I need. So I applied to my data, and in the final it gave me an error "TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable". Do you know how correct that?

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page. Stackoverflow is NOT normal forum. Here is place only for one question and many answers/solutions.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: You could improve your answer avoiding the use of multiple `if-conditional` by using a *hash table* or *dictionary*  that map to each value and key

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).